# How do I modify a rails-bootstrap-forms tabindex in Rails 4

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I've been playing around with Rails for about a year now, and I'm working on my first app that is actually going into production. Since this is a more utilitarian app and it doesn't have to be very flashy, I opted to use the [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) CSS libraries to speed up the UI design.

I'm using the [rails-bootstrap-forms](https://github.com/bootstrap-ruby/rails-bootstrap-forms) gem and I have some text fields in different divs for layout's sake. I'd like to modify the `tabindex` for the fields so the `first_name` and `last_name` fields are next to each other in the tab order. Is there a way to pass the form generator this option?

Here's a snippet of the form HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <%= f.text_field :first_name, label_col: "col-xs-6", control_col: "col-xs-6" %>
    <%= f.text_field :teacher, label_col: "col-xs-6", control_col: "col-xs-6" %>              
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <%= f.text_field :last_name, label_col: "col-xs-6", control_col: "col-xs-6" %> 
    <%= f.text_field :room, label_col: "col-xs-6", control_col: "col-xs-6" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this should work `<%= f.text_field :last_name, label_col: "col-xs-6", control_col: "col-xs-6", :tabindex  => '1' %>`

Comment: So it's really that simple? I guess I was overthinking it. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: It happens sometime...enjoy coding..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the key `tabindex` to the form helper tag.For example,

`<%=f.text_field 'first_name',:tabindex=>1%>`